# Permission of images in bucket with command aws s3 sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have two aws account and i had sync s3 bucket between both account using below command but when i check images in both account do not have same permission i.e source account has public images for particular folder while target account do not have this.

```
aws s3 sync s3://sourcebucket s3://destinationbucket
```

I want exact similar images of source and target with permission, Can any one help?

Comment: This is a known issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/901

Comment: Found that issue today... i copied files from bucketA to bucketB and the owner of bucketB doesn't have permission to files. Any idea how to reset permissions for alle synced files?